# How can we put HTML lists inside a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create a button similar to these:

1. [the orange "Generate Random List" button from here](https://www.randomanime.org)
2. [The grey "Generate Another!" button from here](https://random-ize.com/random-youtube/)

As of now, I've done the following:

=========================================================================

```
   <button id = "button" onclick = "random_element()">click 
   here</button>   
   <h1 style = "color:pink;"> Project Title</h1>
   <p id = "ZZZ" style = "font-size: 14px; color: 
   #a8bcff;"></p>
<script>  
   var zzz = document.getElementById('ZZZ'); 

   var arr = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"];  
 // how do we substitute these strings with HTML lists in arr?
    function random_element() {  
    zzz.innerHTML = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]; 
                                              } 
</script>
```

```
    <ol id="list">
      <li>video1 to be randomly chosen/displayed on button click   </li>
      <li>video2 to be randomly chosen/displayed on button click   </li>
      <li>video3 to be randomly chosen/displayed on button click   </li>
      <li>video4 to be randomly chosen/displayed on button click   </li>
     </ol>
```

=========================================================================

I understand how to generate random elements in the form of text. But I don't know how to make a JS array that contains all of the html lists of  iframes.

What's the proper way to reference and USE html content between <li></li>  tags inside a JavaScript array?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are wanting to accomplish so I am not worrying about your random generator here and just showing how to associate a group of `<li>` by their indexing to the same index in the array shown.

```js
var arr = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"];

const lis = document.querySelectorAll('#list li');

lis.forEach(function(el, i){
   const btn = document.createElement('button');
   btn.textContent = arr[i];
   btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
      // do something with the array value
      console.clear()
      console.log('Btn index:', i, ' array value:', arr[i])
   })
   el.appendChild(btn);
});
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>One  </li>
  <li>Two  </li>
  <li>Three  </li>
  <li>Three  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why did we have to add multiple buttons? The goal was to have one button that's able to get and display the contents of one random <li></li>

Comment: Suggest you use search engine and research each of the methods used. Giving a line by line explanation is tedious and the code used is very standard apporach to looping over a collection of elements and adding event listeners